# Java Locale.getDefault() cannot return values other than en

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

there is some problem I encounter in Java, i want to get system locale country from a window computer, so I write the code like this:

```
 Locale x = Locale.getDefault();
 String output = x.getCountry();
```

If i set my system language to like English(Singapore), i will get result as en-SG, and if i set my system language as English(Canada), it will also return me the result with en-CA, but if i change to some language which is not english, it will return me as en-GB for all options, why is it so??

Besides that, is there any other way to get the current country information using java?

Answer (score 0):

Locale.getDefault() should abstract from the operating system. That is the purpose.

I do not htink that this is a problem of Java. I just tried to change my language and it works.

My Setup was:

1. Windows 10 Home edition 64 Bit
2. Java 1.8.0_45
3. de_DE to en_GB

I had to download the language pack for en_GB.

I had to log off and login in to activate the other language.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! May i ask that when you use language de_DE, did you able to get the locale as de_DE?

Comment: I added the output of the language to your code and executed it on the console after changing the language and logoff/login